# Unions of PSPACE-comlete problems that are PSPACE-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, complexity-classes

Let $A,B\subsetneq\Sigma^*$ be PSPACE-complete problems for some fixed $\Sigma$ such that $A\cup B\neq\Sigma^*$ and $A\cup B\in\mathrm{PSPACE}$. Does it follow that $A\cup B$ is PSPACE-complete?

---

In general, is there a sufficient condition for the union of PSPACE-hard (or complete) problems to be PSPACE-hard (complete)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let $A,B\subsetneq\Sigma^*$ be $\text{PSPACE}$-complete problems for some fixed $\Sigma$ such that $A\cup B\neq\Sigma^*$ and $A\cup B\in\text{PSPACE}$. Does it follow that $A\cup B$ is $\text{PSPACE}$-complete?

The condition "$A\cup B\in\text{PSPACE}$" is redundant since it is always true given that $A,B$ are $\text{PSPACE}$ problems.

It does not follow that $A\cup B$ is $\text{PSPACE}$-complete.
For example, let $A$ be a $\text{PSPACE}$-complete language. Let string $s\notin A$. Let $B=\overline A \setminus\{s\}$, which is a $\text{PSPACE}$-complete language. $A\cup B=\Sigma^*\setminus\{s\}\not=\Sigma^*$ is a language for which the membership problem can be determined in constant space (and constant time). $A\cup B$ is not $\text{PSPACE}$-complete.

---

I don't think people have established any sufficient condition for the union of $\text{PSPACE}$-hard (or complete) problems to be $\text{PSPACE}$-hard (complete) except the obvious ones.

Here is an obvious one. If $A$ is a $\text{PSPACE}$-complete language in which all strings start with $0$ while $B$ is a $\text{PSPACE}$-complete language in which all strings start with $1$, the $A\cup B$ is a $\text{PSPACE}$-complete language.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that PSPACE complete problems are not closed under intersections either? Even if we assume that $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: Correct. For example, let $A$ be PSPACE complete and $s\in A$. Then $A\cap (\overline A\cup\{s\})=\{s\}$. For another example, let $X$ be a PSPACE-complete language and $Y$ a nonempty finite language. Then both $0X\cup Y$ and $1X\cup Y$ are PSPACE-complete. Their intersection is $Y$.